# removing small perpendicular lines on x_axis after using xticklabel changing

Tags: matplotlib

Before using the code below my x*axis was "0.2" , "0.4" , "0.6" , "0.8"

After using the code, the x*_axis was changed into just "inward" , "outward" (which was my goal of using the code below)

Currently, my problem is with the small perpendicular lines on the x_axis, is their any way that I can remove those small lines?

```
x = [0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8]
y = [0, 2, 4, 6]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


fig.canvas.draw()

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]

def update_ticks(x, pos):
    if x == 0.2:
        return 'Outward'
    if x == 0.4:
        return ''
    if x == 0.6:
        return ''
    if x == 0.8:
        return 'Inward'


ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(update_ticks))



plt.errorbar(x, y, color='b', label="Test")
ax.set_xlabel('X_test', fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('Y_test')
plt.legend(),
```

I attached the figure before and after changing the x_axis labeling:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXiwp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlbGS.png)

Comment: `ax.set_xticks([0.2, 0.8], ['Outward', 'Inward']` should set both the tick positions and their labels, omitting the intermediate ticks.